# SLURM/sbatch: pass array ID as input argument of an executable

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, jobs, slurm, sbatch

I'm new to SLURM and I'm trying to do something very natural: I have a compiled C program, `off.exe`, which takes one variable as input, and I want to run it several times in parallel, each with a different value of the input parameter.
I thought I could use the `%a` array iterator as input:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --partition=regular1,regular2
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00                                         # walltime
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                                              # number of processor cores (i.e. tasks)
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=512M                                      # memory per CPU core
#SBATCH --job-name="ISM"                                        # job name
#SBATCH --array=1-60                                            # job array. The item identifier is %a
#SBATCH --output=Polarization_%a_v0.4.txt                       # output file. %A is the job ID

srun ./off.exe %a
```

but it's not working (it's as if the input parameter were always zero!).
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a`, `%j` etc. are replacement symbols for *filenames*, for example in the names of the output and error files recorded by Slurm. For your job arrays, you need to use one of Slurm's output environment variables, probably `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID`. You can find the full list in the manpage for `sbatch`.

Comment: Thanks! For future readers, here's the manpage:
https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html